# FileNotFoundError at /stores/ - Loading local json file into a Django view

Tags: python, django

I have this function:

```
def postcodes(request):
    data = open('stores.json').read() 
    jsonData = json.dumps(data)
```

This is my directory structure:

```
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── stores.json
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── github.html
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       ├── oxford.html
│   │       ├── stores.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

The function is on my `views.py` file, and the file `stores.json` is on the very same directory.

This is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /stores/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/tails/restful-apis-example/core/views.py", line 83, in postcodes
data = open('stores.json').read() #opens the json file and saves the raw contents
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stores.json'
[25/Nov/2018 20:07:31] "GET /stores/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75613
```

I was thinking about declaring something like the `BASE_DIR` for static or templates, but I'm not sure about that approach.

I've never loaded a local json file into Django, so, any ideas on this?

Comment: You will need to use an absolute path. The best way is to join with settings.BASE_DIR.

Comment: Note though that using json.dumps makes no sense, that is for creating JSON from Python datastructures. You have JSON already, if you want to convert it to Python you use json.loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `stores.json` is in core you have to use an absolute path or a relative path from the base directory. ie. `core/stores.json`.
plus use `json.loads(data)`